# how to set buttons visibility in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I wanna know how to control somethings visibility with button clicker

```
VisibilityButton.setOnClickListener(
      makebtninvisible()
)
public void makebtninvisible (View v) {
     Something.setVisibiity(View.INVISILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
VisibilityButton.setOnClickListener{
 VisibilityButton.visibiity=View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
VisibilityButton.setOnClickListener(
 VisibilityButton.visibility = if (VisibilityButton.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
        VisibilityButton.visibiity=View.INVISILE
    } else{
        VisibilityButton.visibiity=View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```